# azure asm reassign vhd lease to disk after break

Tags: python, azure

Is there a way to re-assign the lease of the vhd to disk after it is broken using break_lease as i was doing a disk move and following are my steps
1)break the lease on blob
2)delete the blob
3)copy another blob data to the previous blob name

the server will not start after this operation as the disk doesn't have the lease to the blob

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@Ram,

After view your description, I think you'd like to use the `acquire_blob_lease` to reassign your storage lease. Please see this method:

```
acquire_blob_lease(container_name, blob_name, lease_duration=-1, proposed_lease_id=None, if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, if_match=None, if_none_match=None, timeout=None)
```

For more information, please refer to this document:
https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html